# Android FCM Notification not working in background very first time

Tags: android, firebase

Fcm Notification - onMessageReceived is not called in bacground very first time installed the application. The next time when I opened and closed the application it started working in background. I am testing in Redmi k20 pro android 10 version.

Any Suggestions

**FCM Payload :**

```
{
   "to":"dmYZxw7MkC9y58NIK86dp1xypDkCQKBmikujvVtAFJC....",
   "priority":"high",
   "data":{
      "NotifyId":"12",
      "title":"777",
      "body":"1234456756778787878"
   },
   "notification":{
      "NotifyId":"12",
      "title":"777",
      "body":"1234456756778787878"
   }
}
```

**On Message Received :**

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.d("FROM", remoteMessage.getFrom());
        sendNotification(notification, data);
    }
```

Comment: If you have a bug report, you should send that to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: You said first time not open, does it mean that you installed application and it is not received notification or you have opened application first time and than in background it is not working? can you explain in details, that first you install application than open app etc.

Comment: I installed the app and opened the app very first time and then I closed the application. Now I am sending fcm push  through postman the FCM notification is not showing in app. Again I opened the app and closed app now the FCM notification is showing when the app is in background.

Comment: @ShanmugaM any solution?